# How do I setup replication of Postgres on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

What is the best practice on Heroku for setting up data replication for Postgres so that if the harddrive where my master database is on crashes there is a replica of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a Postgres Follower database that Heroku provides - it's an async read only replication.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases

Comment: Does this mean that Heroku does not support synchronous replication (i.e. Heroku does not support guaranteed no loss of data if the master fails).

Comment: We do support syncrep. Additionally, that's a session variable that you can tweek on a per query basis. Finally, our continuous protection mechanism ships WAL traffic to durable storage: we rebuild entire clusters from these archives with no problem (ie: in case of unrecoverable hardware failure)

Comment: @hgmnz Great, do you have a link to documentation on how to do this?

Comment: You'd go to TFM :) - but for completeness here, just `BEGIN; SET synchronous_commit = on; INSERT INTO table ...; COMMIT;` and you're good to go. That statement will wait until the transaction has completed all the way through to the follower.